# How do you construct a practical full-domain hash function?

Tags: hash

I am looking for practical constructions for Full Domain Hash.

I have read [Random Oracles are Practical](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/ro.pdf) by M. Bellare and P. Rogaway, the construction suggested on page 8, under "Uniformity: a technicality", but it's unclear whether that is producing a full domain hash, or just ensuring the message is well-formed using an existing hash function.

I haven't found any other information regarding full domain hash constructions.

Comment: Full Domain Hash practice that I'm aware of includes RSASSA-PSS as in [PKCS#1v2](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-rsa-cryptography-standard.htm); and [ISO/IEC 9796-2](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec9796-2%7Bed3.0%7Den.pdf) schemes 2 and 3 (which use an ad-hoc mask generation function that concatenate several fixed-width hashes).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if that counts, but authors of recently selected SHA3 function [Keccak](http://keccak.noekeon.org/) mention its ability to perform Full Domain Hashing:

> Variable output length hashing is an interesting feature for natively supporting a wide range of applications including full domain hashing [...]